Why does binary read to a structure miss some bytes?
I am trying to read .bmp file header and show it to console output.
I have two structures for .bmp head info:
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t bmp_file_code{0x424D}; // BMP format code always 0x424D
    uint32_t bmp_file_size{0};      // Whole file size
    uint32_t application_data{0};   // Generally unused
    uint32_t pixel_offset{0};       // Offset to pixel array
};
struct bmp_dib_header{
    uint32_t dib_head_size;         // In bytes. Size of DIB header.
    uint32_t image_width;           // In pixels
    uint32_t image_height;          // In pixels
    uint16_t color_planes;
    uint16_t bits_per_pixel;
    uint32_t compression_method;    // Compression type code
    uint32_t image_size;            // In bytes. width * heigth * color channels count
    int32_t x_resolution;           // In pixels per metre
    int32_t y_resolution;           // In pixels per metre
    uint32_t color_palette;         // Number of colors used (default 0 is 2^n)
    uint32_t important_colors;      // Number of important colors (generally ignored)
};

Here is the read method:
void read_header(std::ifstream &filestream) {
    auto end = filestream.tellg();
    filestream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    if (end - filestream.tellg() <= 0) throw std::runtime_error(strerror(errno));
    
    // Read HEAD
    filestream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmp_head), sizeof(bmp_header));

    // Read Info (DIB-header)
    filestream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmp_dib), sizeof(bmp_dib_header));

}

fileastream is opened with std::ios_base::binary and std::ios_base::in
And output function is:
    void debug_show_header_info() {
        std::cout << "BMP head data:" << std::endl \
        << "File code: " << std::hex << bmp_head.bmp_file_code << std::endl \
        << "File size: " << std::hex << bmp_head.bmp_file_size << std::endl \
        << "Application data: " << std::hex << bmp_head.application_data << std::endl \
        << "Pixel offset: " << std::hex << bmp_head.pixel_offset << std::endl;
    }

In hex editor I have this:
enter image description here
Program give me this:
BMP head data:
File code: 4d42
File size: c    <<< This is not true (0x528F0C actually)
Application data: 8a0000
Pixel offset: 7c0000

It looks like program jump through some bytes (through 4bytes after format code and 4bytes after file size) and I feel stupid for have no idea why it is happening. Thanks in advance.
I tried to read values one by one. Same result.
UPD Here is minimal issue example
Part of the code: https://pastebin.com/W5P9jtGL
Image is sample1.bmp from this site: https://filesampleshub.com/format/image/bmp

Can you provide a [mcve]? In any case, ensure that you imbue your file stream with the C locale, to prevent any code conversion facets from messing with the data.

Reading binary data directly into a struct's object representation is not a portable solution. The result depends on the specific layout and type representation choices of your C++ implementation. Instead handle each byte in the file individually by value and parse/transform it correctly into the individual class members.

After each read call, check the status of the stream (like if (!filestream) { /* There was a problem */ }). Does that tell you anything? What does filestream.tellg() return after each read call?

@UlrichEckhardt The issue is alignment of the second member and the resulting padding.

"I tried to read values one by one. Same result.": No, that should work just fine (except for the representation issues, e.g. endianess).

Related to the comment by @user17732522, please check the actual size of the structures (i.e. print sizeof(bmp_header)). Does that return what you expect? Also see Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?

There are some alternatives to reading each byte individually, such as packing the struct or splitting the size field across two 16-bit fields. That does nothing about endianness, which is a legitimate choice.

@Someprogrammerdude You are right. It caused by structure alignment.

I agree to the prior comments with the alignment and potential endianess problem (if you want that the code can run on a big endian machine). The general approach to decode platform independent data from file or wire is to decode every single simple type field one by one. There you can also apply the correct byte swapping for big endian if necessary.

@WerderFoster What operating system are you using? If it's Windows, there already is a BITMAPINFOHEADER and similar structs defined in wingdi.h, and in there, the structs have #pragma pack(2) invoked on them.

The sizeof(bmp_head) is 10 bytes instead 16 it should be.
This caused due structure alignment.
This helps me: #pragma pack(2) // Pack structures by 2 bytes

If you look at wingdi.h, you can see that BITMAPINFOHEADER uses #pragma pack(2) for this structure by including <pshpack2.h>.  If you are on Windows, you shouldn't need to define your own struct when BITMAPINFOHEADER already exists.

I think you have a typo: sizeof(bmp_head) is 16 bytes instead of 14.
